# UI Bootstrap Typahead async not working in AngularJS RC2

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

Why is the UI Bootstrap Typahead not working in AngularJS RC2 when using the $http service   to retreive matches from server? This was working in AngularJS RC1

See [this plunker using RC1](http://plnkr.co/edit/fQLz5O?p=preview) and [this using RC2](http://plnkr.co/edit/2QbNWL?p=preview)
(test with typing at least 3 letters e.g. 'bos')

#### EDIT:

I´m not sure whether this is an AngularJS issue or UI Bootstrap issue

### Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js:3086:24
at wrappedCallback (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js:9106:81)
at wrappedCallback (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js:9106:81)
at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js:9192:26
at Scope.$eval (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js:10034:28)
at Scope.$digest (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js:9882:23)
at Scope.$apply (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js:10137:24)
at HTMLInputElement.listener (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js:13808:13)
at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js:2277:10
at Array.forEach (native)
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4052

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/949

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known regression of Angular 1.2.0-RC2, that prohibits `$parse()` service from returning a promise. This means that the result of your `$http()` request will be *dropped* (hence returning undefined) at all times.

This [this commit comment](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/3a65822023119b71deab5e298c7ef2de204caa13#commitcomment-4066755) for more details.